# Incrementing a variable to use as serial number in django

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I am currently using forloop.counter to display serial number but it skips the number when if condition is not satisfied. That is why I am not able to print the serial number. I need a way to increment a variable and then use it for serial number

templates.html

```
   {% for all in all_lockscreens %}
    {% if all.media_type == "image" %}
     <tr>
     <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
     <td>{{ all.media_name }}</td>
     <td>{{ all.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ all.date_added }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Need to increment a variable inside if loop which can be used for serial number

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is probably to do `filter(media_type="image")` in your views.py Queryset for all_lockscreens.